# При отправке формы в телеграм, в консоли ошибка "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<br /> <b>"... is not valid JSON" [closed]

Tags: javascript, php, telegram

Пытаюсь отправить форму с сайта на почту и в телеграм. Все раньше работало. Но сейчас ( с нового года, ничего не трогал) непонятно почему возникает ошибка

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<br /> <b>"... is not valid JSON
```

При раскрытии ошибки показывает вот это:

**Warning**:  fopen(https://api.telegram.org/botXXX:XXX/sendMessage?chat_id=XXX&parse_mode=html&text=<b>НОВАЯ ЗАЯВКА</b> %0A<b>Имя: </b> 000%0A<b>Телефон: </b> +7 (000%0A<b>Площадь объекта: </b> 80%0A<b>Количество этажей: </b> 1-5%0A): **failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request** in **/home/zahar850/domains/nurmuhametovu.ru/public_html/sendmail.php** on line **67**

В HTML простая форма с инпутами, там нет незакрытых скобочек и т.п.

JavaScript

```
let formData = new FormData(form); 
let response = await fetch("sendmail.php", { method: "POST", body: formData });
```

PHP

```
$sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

  require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
  require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

  $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
  $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
  $mail->setLanguage("ru", "phpmailer/language/");
  $mail->IsHTML(true);

  $token = "56895XXXXX:AAFQ7js4b9TyqJrbCYTaMxtHbP1677XXXXX";
  $chat_id = "10016258XXXXX";


  // От кого письмо
  $mail->setFrom("info@xxxmuhametovus.ru", "xxxmuhametovus.ru");
  // Кому отправить
  $mail->addAddress("xxxmukhametovusz@mail.ru");
  // Тема письма
  $mail->Subject = "Заявка с xxxmuhametovus.ru";

  // Этажи
  $floor = "1-5";
  if($_POST["floor"] == "1") {
    $floor = "1";
  };
  if($_POST["floor"] == "2") {
    $floor = "2";
  };
  if($_POST["floor"] == "3") {
    $floor = "3";
  };

  $arr = array(
  'НОВАЯ ЗАЯВКА' => "",
  'Имя: ' => $_POST["name"],
  'Телефон: ' => $_POST["phone"],
  'Площадь объекта: ' => $_POST["area"],
  'Количество этажей: ' => $floor
  );

  foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
  };

  // Тело письма
  $body = "<h1>Заявка с xxxmuhametovuus.ru</h1>";

  if(trim(!empty($_POST["name"]))) {
    $body.="<p><strong>Имя:</strong> ".$_POST["name"]."</p>";
  };
  if(trim(!empty($_POST["phone"]))) {
    $body.="<p><strong>Телефон:</strong> ".$_POST["phone"]."</p>";
  };
  if(trim(!empty($_POST["area"]))) {
    $body.="<p><strong>Площадь объекта:</strong> ".$_POST["area"]."</p>";
  };
  if(trim(!empty($_POST["floor"]))) {
    $body.="<p><strong>Количество этажей:</strong> ".$floor."</p>";
  };

  $mail->Body = $body;

  // Отправляем
  $sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");

  if(!$mail->send()) {
    $message = "Ошибка";
  } else {
    $message = "Заявка отправлена!";
  }

  $response = ["message" => $message];

  header("Content-type: application/json");
  echo json_encode($response);
```

И в конце такой кусочек кода:

```
$response = ["message" => $message];

header("Content-type: application/json"); echo json_encode($response)
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема, с других аналогичных форм все отправляется. И раньше она работала. Кто подскажет?

Comment: А обязательно это делать через php?

Comment: Нужно больше информации. 
Работают ли данные ссылки в браузере?
Может изменился бот?  
Если ли рабочие варианты ссылок при максимально одинаковых параметрах?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолмак А в чём проблема?

Answer (score 0):

В общем нашел причину, она не совсем в коде. Почему-то произошла миграция телеграм-чата на другой id. Поменял id телеграм-чата в php и все заработало